# My custom font not setting up in edit text

Tags: android, android-layout

```
mEditText = (EditText) getContentView().findViewById( R.id.custom_text );
AssetManager assests=getContext().getBaseContext().getAssets();
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assests, "fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
mEditText.setTypeface(tf);
```

I am trying to set my custom font using the code given above. Everything goes fine, there is no error, but I am not able to set my custom font to my `EDIT_TEXT`. I am unable to figure out what is happening.

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: @user3519641 just use Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf"); and remove 2nd line.

Comment: when i am doing that its telling me to create a method getAssests() @Indiandroid

Comment: so you are not in an activity class?

Comment: yes i am not on activity class that why i was able to get context through baseContext() method

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

1. First of all you have create "fonts" directory under "assets" directory and put you custom fonts file on "fonts" directory.

2. now try to apply this code here i used my custom fonts "Helvetica LT 45 Light_0.ttf"

XML
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCusomFonts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

Activity
 private EditText edtCusomFonts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtCusomFonts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCusomFonts);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica LT 45 Light_0.ttf");
        edtCusomFonts.setTypeface(tf);

    }
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is inside an activity you are seeting the custom fonts,but my requirments is that it is nly an interface where i am seeting my edittext custom font.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with

```
mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf"));
```

Comment: I tried this also but it dint worked for me it started to say some error on my sdk attr values.

Comment: Than please make a solution  which is given by Haresh in another answer of this post

Comment: I have already stated the problem the problem with me is i am working with one of the sdk and on that sdk i want to put custom fonts from myside as they are not providing the custom fonts rigth for now