# how to create custom font in android?

Tags: android

How can i use the custom font which we add in asset folder in xml?
I want to create custom font for app..
but I run the programme ,it has exception.
this is my java code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends TextView {

  private static final String TAG = "TextView";

    public MainActivity(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MainActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public MainActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.textfont);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }


}
```

and create a folder in res/values/attrs

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
   <declare-styleable name="textfont">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
 </resources>
```

and xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.changfont"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.example.changfont.MainActivity
    android:id="@+id/textViewPlus1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="helooo"
    foo:customFont="aaa.ttf">
</com.example.changfont.MainActivity>
```

logcat is:

```
 09-09 20:44:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(11515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-09 20:44:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(11515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.changfont/com.example.changfont.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.changfont.MainActivity; no empty constructor
 09-09 20:44:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(11515):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
```

I do not know what the problem is ?
please help me.

Comment: Maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12128450/3681056

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Comment: try [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3651168/3326331](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3651168/3326331)

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599333/getting-error-in-setting-custom-text-style-in-my-application/25600041#25600041

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` is not an `Activity` but a `TextView`. It cannot be instantiated as an activity and should not be declared in the manifest.

Looks like you need to:

- Rename this `MainActivity` to something like `MyCustomTextView``
- Implement `MainActivity` as an activity that calls `setContentView()` with a layout that contains an instance of your `MyCustomTextView`, such as the XML you posted (with `MainActivity` renamed).